# Tableau WDC V3.0 Authenticate API call

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I'm attempting to write a WDC for Tableau that connects to an external API that requires an access token. With Tableau's recent switch to v3 for WDC I can't seem to find how to add authentication to the external API call. Please note this is not the authentication for the WDC itself but rather the API that happens inside of the WDC. I've looked through their SDK, and can't seem to find out how it works. Everything I find is either for V2 of the WDC or for authenticating the WDC itself. Unless I'm missing something...

Here is the resources I've checked so far:

- https://help.tableau.com/current/api/webdataconnector/en-us/reference/index.html
- https://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/docs/
- community forum

I guess in the fetcher I could manually call the URL with an axios call that sets the header. Is this a good practice?

example fetcher code:

```
import { Fetcher, FetchUtils } from '@tableau/taco-toolkit/handlers'

export default class DataFetcher extends Fetcher {
  async *fetch({ handlerInput }) {
    const headers = {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.API_TOKEN}`
    };

    yield await axios.get(handlerInput.data.url, { headers })
        .then(response => {
          return response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
          log('Internal Server Error');
          return null
        });
  }
}
```

UPDATE: Posted my answer below. Was not able to use axios because the service worker doesn't play kindly with it, so fetch has to be used. I misunderstood the documentation for the FetchUtils.fetchJson call, fixing my code to what I posted below ended up working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
import {Fetcher, FetchUtils} from '@tableau/taco-toolkit/handlers'
import {API_TOKEN} from "../constants";

export default class DataFetcher extends Fetcher {
    async *fetch({handlerInput}) {
        const headers = {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_TOKEN}`
        };
        yield await FetchUtils.fetchJson(handlerInput.data.url, { headers })
    }
}
```